# Bounding an angle from below

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, trigonometry, inequality

I have the following expression

$\arccos\left(\frac{-D^2 + 4 L^2 \cos{2 \delta} - 4DL \sin{\delta}}{
 D^2 + 4 L^2 + 4 DL \sin{\delta}}\right)$

I know that $d \leq \rho M$, $L \leq \frac{1-\rho}{1-2\rho}M$, $\delta \leq \frac{\rho}{1-\rho}$, and that $0 < \rho < 0.5$.

I want to argue that after replacing the quantities in my expression with these bounds the result angle I get is larger that it would be if I knew the exact values. This is equivalent to showing that the quantity 
$\frac{-D^2 + 4 L^2 \cos{2 \delta} - 4DL \sin{\delta}}{
 D^2 + 4 L^2 + 4 DL \sin{\delta}}$
decreases, as $\arccos$ is a decreasing function.

Any solutions or suggestions would be appreciated.